# The C programming Language excercise 1 - 13

Tags: c

I am going though the "The C Programming Language" by K & R. I am trying to do the exercise 1-13, to get the histogram of length of words of it input. Following is what I tried. I am not getting the last word length.
How do I correct this ?

```
#define space ' '
#define maxLength 100
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int c, result[maxLength], count, i, maxWordLength;
  count = maxWordLength = 0;
 for (i = 0; i < maxLength; ++i)
    result[i] = 0;
  while ((c = getchar ()) != '0') {
    if (!((c == space) || (c == '\t') || (c == '\n')))
        ++count;
    else {
      ++result[count];
      if (count > maxWordLength)
        maxWordLength = count;
      count = 0;
    }
  }
  for (i = 1; i <= maxWordLength; ++i)
    printf("\n%d\t%d\n", i, result[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

Following is my input

```
1 12
123 1234    12345
1234560
```

and the output comes like this, it is not giving last word length

```
1   1

2   1

3   1

4   1

5   1
```

I have understood why does it happen. But how do I correct it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reach the `0` that terminates the input you just exit the loop, without adding the length of the last word to the histogram. A possible fix is adding this after the loop:

```
   ...
}
/* Take last word into account */
++result[count];
if (count > maxWordLength)
maxWordLength = count;
```

This is of course assuming that the `0` character indicates the end of the input and is not part of the data.

Comment: if the last word size is less than `maxWordLenght`?

Comment: Ah true, it should be `count` then, fixed. If there is whitespace after the last word and before the terminating `0` the program would now increment the count for words of length 0, but that's a value you don't use so it doesn't matter.

Comment: and this too `if (count > maxWordLength)
        maxWordLength = count;` right?

Comment: Right, otherwise `maxWordLength` will incorrect if the last word is the longest word in the file.

Answer (score 3):

```
while ((c = getchar ()) != '0')
```

should be

```
while ((c = getchar ()) != EOF)
```

otherwise your program stops at the first `0` character, e.g. in `1234560`.
And if the last input line is not terminated by a newline, you have to take that also into account.

`EOF` is returned at end-of-file or if a read error occurs.